# How to make array ( with a datatype of a class ) with undefined size

Tags: c++

**My Question:**

I have a file which look like following:

```
INPUT(1)
INPUT(2)
INPUT(3)
INPUT(6)
INPUT(7)

OUTPUT(22)
OUTPUT(23)

10 = NAND(1, 3)
11 = NAND(3, 6)
16 = NAND(2, 11)
19 = NAND(11, 7)
22 = NAND(10, 16)
23 = NAND(16, 19)
```

Now, I read this file and try to find the word `NAND`. If I find the word `NAND` then I want to push its ID (which is `10` for the first 
line) into an array.

**Problem:** The array in which I want to push the ID of NAND should be of `Class Node` type. How do I do that?

**PS:** I need the array to be of `Node` type because then I call another method which do the processing on two `nodes` E.g. `wire(Node* a, Node*b);`

Comment: If you don't understand the "format" of `std::vector`, that means you're not able to use templates. Consult your C++ book.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Sorry, i meant that i don't understand how do i use it here ...i know how to use `vector`

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar It also mean that she's unable to read basic documentation, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back so I am unsure anything we write here can help her.

Comment: @user2756695: Re:IMPORTANT, please explain why this isn't the proper solution.

Comment: Please clarify *what exactly* you don't know about `std::vector` which makes you not use it. That's far more productive than simply avoiding such a powerful class, which use case is exactly the one you're describing (i.e. dynamic sized array).

Comment: "i don't know the name of the array" - this does not make sense. Please be more specific in the description. Voting to close for now.

Comment: You read some name from the file and then want to add an element to an array. What do you want to add? Where does it come from? What is `Node`? Do you want to look for an existing `Node` somewhere by looking up a name? This is still very confusing.

Comment: i meant"dont know the size of array"

Comment: I don't get why you say: I have a class Node and then you write: I need something like this: Node* p[].. Have you coded this class or do you need some help writing it?

Comment: @user2756695: It looks like usage of `std::vector` and e.g. `push_back` or `resize` is still the answer to your question.

Comment: That's ok to not to know the size of an array, initially you don't know the size of a vector (actually you sort of know, but that's below this thread of conversation). Why do you want to stick to an array instead of a `std::vector` ?

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to use `std::vector<Node>` but you can use a `std::vector<Node *>` (i.e. storing the pointers, like in your *undefined size* array)

Comment: But why do you need a Class Node when you can simply use std::vector and achieve the same result with fewer and faster code..

Comment: The question remains unclear: you want to work with an array to which you want to add entries, but you're sure you don't want to use vector (maybe deque then?) and you want to add objects of an unknown class Node, but you only read in a name from a file.

Comment: @Emi987: Because then i need to call another method which process two `node`. E.g. process(Node* a, Node* b);

Comment: @user2756695: People downvoted your question because your rejected  an apparently good solution without giving the reason. Removing all code doesn't make your question better, but only worse.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: I have written the reason below. I can't push the node because i have only its ID which is to be pushed in.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question is misleading because the title and the text concentrate on how to put something in an array of unknown size, while the actual problem seems to be, how to create an instance of `class Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy:

include the header for vector:

```
#include <vector>
```

declare a vector, of type `Node`:

```
std::vector<Node> nodes;
```

and when you have created a new `Node` object:

```
nodes.push_back(my_new_node);
```

Also, you can have a vector of `Node*` if you really want to manage the memory on your own. Please note, that it is also possible to get the address of an object (`Node`) from the vector but you have to be careful to not to trust it between operations on the vector.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question ... hm...

Comment: @fritzone: yes, my question is different

Comment: @user2756695 Then please refine it ... Noone seems to understand it :( Elaborate why this answer is not the solution.

Comment: again updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your "not the solution" into a solution:

```
std::vector<Node> nodes; // dynamic array of type Node
Node my_new_node; // create a Node instance
my_new_node.name = input_name; // set it's name or do whaterver you want with it
nodes.push_back(my_new_node); // add it to the array
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are a statically sized collection;

```
Node myNodes1[ARRAY_SIZE];
Node *myNodes2=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)*ARRAY_SIZE);
```

This means you must define their size at compile time and runtime respectively, so they are not greatly suitable for your requirements.

`std::vector` is a dynamically sized collection. Generally the internals of such dynamically sized collections will malloc a pointer array of a size (usually this size can be specified via their constructor). After that array is filled, a new array of double the size is allocated and the contents of the primary array is copied to it, then the first array freed.

People are suggesting you use `std::vector` because it will abstract away the technicality of having to keep adjusting the size of your array manually.

---

Your updated question suggests your trying to put a `string` (or `int` if you have parsed the value) into an array or vector of `Node`. To do this you would need to construct an instance of `Node` using the value, and then pass that to your collection, how to do this will be specific to your `Node` objects constructor. Possibly of the form;

```
std::vector<Node> nodes;
//for file
    //where node found
        Node t_node(id);
        nodes.push_back(t_node);
```